# How to add dictionaries, arrays as custom properties in java data source library to Google visualization (chart)

Tags: java, google-visualization

I can add custom properties through java data source library, like this:

```
...
DataTable dt=new DataTable();
dt.setCustomProperty("title","chart3");
return JsonRenderer.renderDataTable(dt, true, false, false);
```

I am getting in trouble when I try to do any of the following:

```
dt.setCustomProperty("colors", "['green']");
```

or

```
dt.setCustomProperty("hAxis", "{title: 'Hello',titleTextStyle: {color: '#FF0000'}}");
```

Can anybody help me out what is the right syntax to pass a string array and/or a data dictionary correctly?

Thanks in advance,
Roland

Comment: try removing the quotes --> `dt.setCustomProperty("colors", ['green']);`

Comment: @WhiteHat the setCustomeProperty expects two string parameters. I also tried to use the green with and without quotes but none of them worked. I got back the following error in the browser: "Invalid color: ["

Comment: setCustomProperty should accept any type of value for the second argument.

Comment: @dlaliberte, If I check the DataTable class on Github, the following method signature is used:
/**
   * Sets a custom property.
   *
   * param propertyKey The property key.
   * param propertyValue The property value.
   */
  public void setCustomProperty(String propertyKey, String propertyValue)

Comment: @Roland, That should be fixed then.  I don't know who is responsible for that Github file.